# AWS adding inline/managed policy to an role doesn't take effect immediately?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Say I have a policy with following statement:

```
{
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Action": "organizations:*",
  "Resource": "*",
}
```

I am trying to add such inline policy to a role through AWS SDK:

```
PutRolePolicyRequest request = new PutRolePolicyRequest()
   .withRoleName("TestRole")
   .withPolicyName("TestPolicy")
   .withPolicyDocument("Above in string");
PutRolePolicyResult result = iam.putRolePolicy(request);

// I would need to uncomment below for test to pass
// Thread.sleep(10000)
assertThatThrownBy(() -> {
    awsOrgs.listAccounts(..); 
}).isInstanceOf(AccessDeniedException.class)
```

*Note* the comment above where I have to add a delay for `awsOrgs.listAccounts()` to throw a exception, otherwise the test fails indicating there was no exception thrown. Is this some kind of eventual consistency problem AWS has going on?

Comment: Yes, it takes some time for the newly added policy to take affect.

Comment: Wouldn't this make testing more difficult or am I missing something? I thought `iam.putRolePolicy(request)` would be a blocking call until policy is added.

Comment: IAM is a global service that is replicated to other regions. I think all operations take place in us-east-1, then the results are replicated to other regions. So, the replication can take a while. The 'blocking' concept wouldn't work because it takes place _after_ the request is completed.